# next element in 2 array loop php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. I have 2 array. First one is Sections and second one Lessons. I'm trying to get $next_lesson id element using this code:

```
foreach ($sections as $key => $section):
  $lessons = $this->crud_model->get_lessons('section', $section['id'])->result_array();
    foreach ($lessons as $key => $lesson):
       $current_lesson = $lesson['id'];
       $next = $lessons[$key+1];
       $next_lesson = $next['id'];
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Javascript redirect:

```
  window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('home/lesson/')."/".$course_id."/".$next_lesson; ?>";
```

but after 1 lesson loop $next_lesson getting first value of section 1. What should I do to move to the second part when the last lesson of the first part is over?

[Database structure screenshot if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td2ZQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it is more about data structure in the database and querying it than a php algorithm (this 2 loops force you to query all the lessons and it might be time consuming).

First of all you'd have to ask yourself : what is the ordering parameter ? (it is not obvious in the screenshot provided).

Let's say it's the `order` (edited from comment) field, that is unique among all the lessons (not reset for a new section). In such a case, a new sql query would be :

```sql
    SELECT * -- or just id 
    FROM lesson
    WHERE `order` > ?
    ORDER BY `order` ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

With the parameter (the `?`) equals to the current lesson `order` field, generally passed with the method of the ORM used to query the Database.

Comment: Every section has "order" parameter in database. For example;

lesson1 in section1 order 0
lesson3 in section1 order 1
lesson2 in section1 order2

https://ibb.co/YbQmkgV

Comment: Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I got it but I can't change database structure anymore. can I solve it with php algorithm?

Comment: No need to change it since the `order` field is already here, just to query it. In plain php (not advised) that would be : [sorting](https://www.php.net/sort) the lessons by their orders, iterate until reaching the current one, take the next one.